# Eclipse CDT .exe file not executing outside of IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am creating a C++ program called Choose Your Own Adventure, using Eclipse CDT and MinGW, and whenever I run the .exe file from building the program, Debug build or Release, whether it be from The Command Line or by double clicking it, I get this error message.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP22X.png)

(Note that none of this happens if I use the Run option in Eclipse to run the program)

Could anyone offer some insight on what this error is and how to fix it?

Comment: You should include the error message as text in the question itself rather than linking to an off-site image.

Comment: I can give insights, but I don't have full solution. The problem here looks like Eclipse CDT is setting your run environment variables, probably to include some entries in the PATH that contain the c++ libraries your program needs. Try starting the mingw (msys) shell and running from within there, or look at the environment that Eclipse CDT is using. Once you have that you should be able to change the compiler settings to include some of that within the link stage. An answer like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1317149/2796832 may be of some help.