# The C++ vector class does not run on my computer if a vector has data inside. It compiles but will not run

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

I asked a question about this earlier but I hadn't done hours of research yet. My C++ compiler appears to be fine, but my computer cannot run .exe which were compiled from C++ code using the vector class if the vector has any contents. Here is some extremely basic code that cannot run (no errors thrown, nothing is printed) as a result of this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello!\n");
    std::vector<int> myints;
    // myints.push_back(1);
    // vector<int> myvector = {10,20,30,40,50};
    return 0;
}
```

With both of those two lines commented out, the code prints Hello! as expected. If either line is uncommented, my computer cannot run the .exe that is built. I thought this was likely a compiler issue so I uninstalled and reinstalled g++ on Windows. Same results.

Then I had a friend compile my code, both with the lines commented and uncommented. He sent me the resulting .exes. The one with both lines commented produced the Hello! output, the one with them uncommented did not. I compiled the code (lines uncommented) and sent him the .exe and it ran.

This is not an issue unique to my compiler, this is coming from my machine somehow. I can do other C++ stuff just fine, like allocating space for an array with malloc() but I want to append stuff onto a list so I need vector to work.

Comment: You'll have to define "cannot run".

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run(double click on)  the executable? Also, did you try other library containers like `std::array` or `std::list` etc. Do you get the same problem with them as well?

Comment: Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316747/how-is-the-c-standard-library-linked-to-my-application. Somehow I think your exe cannot find those libraries at runtime.

Comment: There are no errors. There are no outputs either. When it runs, it prints Hello. When it doesn't run, it looks just the same as hitting enter on the command line without any commands.

Comment: Have you tried other compilers like clang? You should probably tag your question with gcc as well IMO.

Comment: `using namespace std` can be very dangerous, you never know what symbols it will pull into your code.  Better to be explicit about things, e.g. `using std::vector`.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that your program is crashing hard before the "Hello" can be flushed to the stream.  But I can't imagine how your commented out lines would do that.

Comment: The problem is not necessarily with your compiler - it may also be related to how you are running the program.   You need to describe *exactly* how you are running the program.  What is your host system?   Are you running it by clicking (or double-clicking) on an icon, are you typing a command into a command line interpreter or shell, or are you running it within an IDE?

Comment: I'm on Windows using VSCode and the instructions from here to set it up with Mingw64. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_example-install-mingwx64. I run it from the PowerShell command line provided by VSCode by typing ./filename
I agree though, because I could build something to be run on another machine the compiler seems fine.

Comment: Try to explicitly flush the output.

Comment: My guess would be either your executable can't find the standard library dlls on the path or it is finding a different version of them to the one that your code is compiled against. Using a debugger night help you find out which is the case

Comment: *"I uninstalled and reinstalled g++"* - Have you considered using a supported compiler, such as MSVC? MinGW and MinGW64 are pretty much unsupported. And VSCode is utter garbage. Just install Visual Studio and you can concentrate on making forward progress. Added bonus: Visual Studio comes with a real debugger.