# Error when trying to output element of a standard array that is a struct member

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct newperson {
    std::array<char, 20> name{};
    int age;
};

int main() {
    newperson nicolas = {
        "Nicolas",
        21
    };

    newperson martin = {
        "Martin",
        45
    };

    std::cout << nicolas.age << std::endl;
    std::cout << martin.name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

, which is a struct example

I get the following errors:

```
bast.cpp: In function 'int main()':
bast.cpp:21:19: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'std::array<char, 20>')
   21 |         std::cout << martin.name << std::endl;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              |              |
      |              |              std::array<char, 20>
      |              std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}

C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/ostream:754:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
```

Is some different syntax required? I did take an existing example and change the C-style array to a standard one, after all.

And if I comment out the Martin lines, I get the following:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccClI6JG.o:bast.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccClI6JG.o:bast.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccClI6JG.o:bast.cpp:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccClI6JG.o:bast.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccClI6JG.o:bast.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_[.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_]+0x0): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccClI6JG.o:bast.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout[.refptr._ZSt4cout]+0x0): undefined reference to `std::cout'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

That seems to be a problem with mingw/msys2, though, because it works with Godbolt and tio.run

Comment: It is not an issue of mingw. There is no `<<` for `std::array<char, 20>`. Why do you not use `std::string` ?

Comment: `std::array<T>` is not an alias of `T[]`, it's more like a safe (and basically equally efficient) wrapper. If you want to get the pointer, `.data()` will do it.

Comment: btw your title says that you are trying to print an element of the array, that would work

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number are you talking about the first block of error messages? That may not have to do with mingw, but something's definitely wrong: when trying to compile [this[(https://pst.moe/paste/lpsnaq) I get [this](https://pst.moe/paste/ytkaum). If I use g++ instead of gcc, I get `g++: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': spawn: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Interestingly, this only started after I installed mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc. When I was using msys2's gcc, it worked fine.

Comment: no I am only refering to `std::cout << martin.name << std::endl;` which is an error, because there is no `<<` for `std::array`. On the other hand `std::cout << martin.name[0] << std::endl;` would be fine to print an element of the array. I admit, i didnt even read the error message you posted

Comment: You should be using `g++`, not `gcc`. Reinstall your MSYS2 if it doesn't work. `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` is the correct package, don't even install the plain `gcc`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat reinstalling msys2 didn't work.

Comment: Are you running the commands from the MSYS2 shell or some other shell? (try the former) Do you have a different version of MinGW also installed and in PATH? (if yes, remove it)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It worked now. I just had to use the mintty that comes with MSYS2 (I was using cmder before). Weird

Comment: @gps I bet the PATH is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no overloaded `<<` (stream output) operator for the `std::array` container, whatever the element type. However, that array container does have a `.data()` member, which yields a pointer to the first element; in your case, that will be a `char*` and the relevant specialisation for outputting a `char*` (assuming that points to a properly null-terminated string/array) will do what you want:

```cpp
std::cout << martin.name.data() << std::endl;
```

But, as pointed out in the comments, you would be far better off using a `std::string`, here, unless there is a specific reason why you need a fixed-length array in your structures.

(If you adapted this from code that used a "C-style" array for the `.name` member – i.e. `char name[20];` – then the `<<` would work because that array name will *automatically* 'decay' into a pointer to its first element; this doesn't happen for `std::array`.)

Alternatively, although there is no `<<` `ostream` overload for the `array<char, N>` container provided by the Standard Library, you *could* provide your own. This can be implemented as a function template (so that different array sizes could be used), like this:

```c
template <size_t N>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, std::array<char, N> ArrChar)
{
    return os << ArrChar.data();
}
```

Comment: The linker error is unrelated to the issue I have addressed here. That almost certainly means that you need to add the standard library as input to the linker: not exactly sure how to do that for your mingw-64 system, but its *probably* something like a `-llibstc++` switch. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316763/10871073) may help.

Comment: -llibstdc++ didn't work. I'll try reinstalling MSYS2. maybe should opt for cygwin or wsl instead

Comment: @gps I'm not really surprised. It was just a sort of 'guess'. But the comments on your question may be more helpful. Also, that second point appears to make your post into *two* questions. Perhaps the second issue should be made into a second, separate question. The main issue (which I have addressed) stands alone as its own question.

Comment: @gps Those three serve different purposes, and none of them is fundamentally broken. MSYS2 produces Windows binaries. Cygwin produces Windows binaries with a POSIX emulation layer. WSL produces Linux binaries.

Comment: @gps You should pick the tool based on the kind of binaries you want to produce, then make it work.